# Change/Add/Remove items from the New File/Folder option in the right click options (Windows 7-8)?

Tags: windows

When you right+click in a folder or desktop whitespace, there is a menu item at the bottom `New`, which gives you new file/folder options.

[image]

I rarely create new empty Rich Text Format files, or Journal Documents, however there are several files that I do create that would be handy to have there.

Any ideas how to customize this menu?

Comment: programatically or is it a one time manual action?

Comment: one time would be fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ShellNewHandler is an Open-Source Tool to enable/disable ShellNew
>   entries, aka New File context menu entries from Windows Explorer in
>   Vista and Windows 7. Check or uncheck items to enable a desktop
>   right-click context menu item. No need to install.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/shellnewhandler/

Comment: i think it only allows you to remove exiting entries right now, but by looking at what registry keys are changed you can add new ones yourself.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows, whenever right-click on Desktop or in Windows Explorer, a "New" menu allows to create new folder, new shortcut and new files.

To remove unwanted items from "New" menu, it is some time difficult to idenfied the extention of those items.

Following this method will help :

1. Type `regedit` in RUN dialog box and press Enter. Now expand "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT" key.
2. Now find item with a "FileName" with Edit/Find menu - Repeat untill you find the file type which you want to remove from "New" menu, e.g. for removing MP3 file type look for .MP3 key.
3. Expand it and delete the "FileName" value in "ShellNew" key.
4. That's it. The file type will be removed from "New" menu.